# Convert a Postman format Post Request Body to Fiddler 4

Tags: request, postman, fiddler

My client's developer sent me a Postman Post Request Body sample in a format that I'm not sure how to enter into Fiddler 4.

In the Postman Body (raw):

```
{
          "userCredential":
          {
                         "userId": "myemail80@mailhost.com",
                         "password": "Password1"
          }
}
```

I copied just the UserId and password parts into the top part of Fiddler composer, and other values in the lower "Request Body" in Fiddler:

```
 userId: myemail80@mailhost.com
 password: Password1
```

Do I need to encode "userCredential" and if so, how?

Comment: The Postman body is apparent in JSON. Have you tried to just use it as body data of a POST request in Fiddler and add the header `Content-Type: application/json`?

Comment: Yes. But at first I was placing the header info in the body section.  Now that I have the body (json credentials) in the "Request Body" section I am getting other errors, but getting closer to having it resolved.  Thanks.